# Can SMB read only changed data from a server

Tags: smb

Suppose a smb client has read a file from a SMB server. 
If I close the read file and re-open it again (provided that file has not changed on server), will server send the whole file content again to client?

I tried it on SMB 2.1 and 3 as well. Checked network traffic via wireshark. it shows that the whole file data is sent back to client again. 
Is there any setting though which we can re-read the data from client cache, instead of going back to server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SMB does not support this kind of feature.
The protocol have a command called "changeNotify" for getting changes on a folder but this is available only if you are "listening" on a Folder.

If you want to get the data from the Client cache , you need to implement file caching.
* Once you read the data you need to save it wherever and after you close the file you can read the data from "this" place.